# Uniqueness of basis in a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics

I know that any vector in a vector space can be uniquely represented as a linear combination of its basis i.e. components of a vector are unique. My question is that if my components of a vector are unique then how to prove that my basis would be unique?

My attempt to the question assuming finite n-dimensional space :

As we know that in a finite-dimensional space there can be many basis but the cardinality of all these basis has to be same ( in this case n) i.e dimensionality = n.

Let {$ v_1, v_2, .... ,v_n $} and {$v'_1, v'_2, .... ,v'_n$} be the basis of the V.S.

v= $a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 +...... + a_n v_n$

v= $a_1 v'_1 + a_2 v'_2 +...... + a_n v'_n$

Now, writing {$v'_1, v'_2, .... ,v'_n$} in terms of {$ v_1, v_2, .... ,v_n $} considering latter the basis of V.S.

I got the whole bunch of equations from which I am not able to see how to prove $v_i =v'_i$  $ \forall$ i.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only time that a basis for a vector space is unique is when the vector space has dimension $0$, or when the vector space has dimension $1$ over the field with two elements. Not really sure what it is you think you are trying to prove...

Comment: What *is* true is that $\beta$ and $\beta’$ are two bases with the property that for any vector $v$, $[v]_{\beta}=[v]_{\beta’}$ (where $[x]_{\gamma}$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to the basis $\gamma$), then $\beta=\beta’$. The simplest way to prove that is to take, instead of a random vector $v$, the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ from the first basis, one at a time.

Comment: I would think about these two cases but my question is a bit different. I am trying to prove   that if components of a vector are unique then would basis also be unique? I am applying the same reasoning as we apply when we say that the components have to be unique a vector.

Comment: Again: are you trying to prove that if you have two bases, $\beta$ and $\beta’$, and for every vector $v$ you have that the coordinate vector of $v$ relative to $\beta$ is the same as the coordinate vector of $v$ relative to $\beta’$, then $\beta=\beta’$? Or that if this holds for a **particular** vector $v$ then $\beta=\beta’$? The latter is false if you do not require $v\neq 0$.

Comment: I am asking about the former one.

Comment: Then just take $v_1$: the way to express it in terms of the first basis is $v_1=1v_1+0v_2+\cdots + 0v_n$, so the way to express it in terms of the second basis is $v_1=1v’_1 +0v’_2+\cdots + 0v’_n=v’_1$. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Sorry if am terribly wrong here but shouldn't $v_1= a_1v'_1 + a_2 v'_2 + ....+ a_n v'_n$? Why a_1=1 and all others are equal to 0?

Comment: Because you are assuming that the way to express $v_1$ in terms of $\beta’$ is the same as the way to express it in terms of $\beta$: the coefficients are supposed to be the same, so they are: $1$ for the first vector, $0$ for the rest of the vectors.

Comment: Ahh I should have got it. I was taking any random vector v which was making things difficult. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, let me rephrase the question:

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $\beta=\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\beta’=\{v’_i\}_{i\in I}$ be two ordered bases (same index bset because they have the same cardinality), with the property that for every vector $v\in V$, if we express $v$ as a linear combination of vectors in $\beta$,
>   $$v = \sum_{i\in I}\alpha_iv_i,\qquad \alpha_i=0\text{ for almost all }i\in I,$$
>   and we do the same in terms of $\beta’$,
>   $$v = \sum_{i\in I}\alpha’_iv’_i,\qquad \alpha’_i=0\text{ for almost all }i\in I$$
>   then $\alpha_i=\alpha’_i$ for every $i\in I$. Then $\beta=\beta’$.

This is true. To verify this, fix $i_0\in I$, and consider how to express $v_{i_0}$ as a linear combination of $\beta$: 
$$v_{i_0} = 1v_{i_0} + \sum_{i\in I-\{i_0\}}0v_i.$$

By assumption, the way to express $v_{i_0}$ in terms of $\beta’$ is
$$v_{i_0} = 1v’_{i_0} + \sum_{i\in I-\{i_0\}}0v’_i.$$
But the latter expression is just $v’_{i_0}$. Hence, $v_{i_0}=v’_{i_0}$.

As this holds for an arbitrary $i_0\in I$, it follows that $\beta=\beta’$.

---

By the way, the other interpretation, that the assertion holds for a single (nonzero) vector $v$, is false if $\dim(V)\gt 1$. To see this, take $\beta$, and take two vectors in $\beta$, $v_1,v_2$. Let $\beta’$ be the basis obtained by replacing $v_2$ with $v_1+v_2$. Then every vector in $\mathrm{span}(\beta-\{v_2\})$ has the same expansion relative to $\beta$ as relative to $\beta’$, but $\beta\neq \beta’$.